# create database automatically in django using settings.py or models.py

Tags: python, django

Current flow:

```
1) mysql >> CREATE {DATABASE} db_name  [create_specification] ;
2) change database info in settings.py
3) python manage.py syncdb (assuming we have ready-made models)
```

Isn't there a way to do the same without using step 1. Maybe putting database name and specifications somewhere in settings.py so that i don't have to manually configure the db everytime i shift this project to some server

**EDIT** -
WHY I want to dodge the first step:

In my case, different columns of different tables have different collation types. So while development, whenever I recreate the database, i need to manually change the configurations of individual columns/tables, which is frustrating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you **need is to know database user / password with grant create database**, all other data is in settings. You can **connect a custom command to [pre_syncdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#pre-syncdb) signal** to gather this data.

Take a look to [createsuperuser](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py) that is raised on post_syndb signal to learn about this.

**EDITED**

syncdb is not longer available. Since 1.9 you should to use [pre_migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#pre-migrate) signal.

Comment: Please add a go through example. For novice like me this is almost like gibberish.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think its possible to dodge the step one, at least if you're using a different database backend except SQLite in django.

A note from docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#database-setup

> If you’re using PostgreSQL or MySQL, make sure you’ve created a
>   database by this point. Do that with “CREATE DATABASE database_name;”
>   within your database’s interactive prompt.
>
> If you’re using SQLite, you don’t need to create anything beforehand -
>   the database file will be created automatically when it is needed.

If you move your project to a server like Heroku, the db creation is automated, like when using PostgreSQL.

I'm wondering why you want to dogde the first step, however if you're desperate, you might still want to trying going the direct python way via psycopg2

[Creating a postgresql DB using psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426448/creating-a-postgresql-db-using-psycopg2)

Answer (score 2):

Done via [django_extensions](https://pypi.org/project/django-extensions/):

```
1) ./manage.py sqlcreate | ./manage.py dbshell
2) ./manage.py migrate
```

If at least the user on settings.py is already able to connect on the DB and have creation permissions, this should work.

To have it, I suggest to provide an envvar DATABASE_URL and use [dj_database_url](https://pypi.org/project/dj-database-url/)

At least is working for me on Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Granting the overall application database creation permissions to spare a minor manual initialization at deployment time sounds like a bad idea.

You should rather create a separate script that automates deployment for you. [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) seems to have become the standard tool for that.

Answer (score -2):

You can use sqlite while you are still in development stage.

Comment: It is not always possible. What about array fields which are supported in postgres but not in sqlite